# "Unexpected token '<' " with electron forge + vite + react

Tags: reactjs, electron, vite, electron-forge

I'm building an electron app using electron forge, the vite template, and react. I built my app using

```
npm init electron-app@latest my-new-app -- --template=vite
```

Which displays the hello world vite application just fine. Then I installed react

```
npm install --save react react-dom
```

This is my renderer.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App.jsx'

const el = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(el);

root.render(<App />);
```

But when I execute the program I get the following error. `caught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` and it points to the line `root.render(<App />);`

Additionally I've installed @vitejs/plugin-react and my vite.renderer.config.mjs looks like this.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

What I'm reading online is that it's not transpiling the jsx code to javascript properly, and most of the solutions involve using babel with webpack to accomplish this. However, my understanding was that vite was supposed to provide this function and I haven't found any help with vite.

edit:

Here is App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Comment: can you please post the code present in `App.tsx` file as well ?

Comment: @StaticMethod did you link the correct compiled file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vite doesn't support JSX in `.js` files, you need to rename `renderer.js` to `renderer.jsx`. Here is [a discussion](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/3112) on this subject.